# Grep a word from a file

Tags: linux, shell, grep

How can i grep a nearer word from a file ?

E.g

```
04-02-2010  Workingday
05-02-2010  Workingday
06-02-2010  Workingday
07-02-2010  Holiday
08-02-2010  Workingday
09-02-2010  Workingday
```

I stored above data in a file 'feb2010',

By this commend i stored date in one variable date=`date '+%d-%m-%Y'`

if date is 06-02-2010 , i want to grep "06-02-2010" with Workingday

and want to store the string "Workingday" in a variable

- How can i do this ?
- Is there any other option ?

Comment: Crossposted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176261/how-can-i-grep-a-nearer-word-from-a-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```
DATE=$(date '+%d-%m-%Y')
DAY=$(grep $DATE feb2010 | awk '{ print $2 }')
echo $DAY
```

This greps for your `$DATE` and selects the second column for the output via awk and stores this output in the variable `$DAY`.

Comment: I've posted answers with backticks and been downvoted for it, but nothing wrong with it, I say.

Comment: you should use `$( )` instead. Not all keyboard layouts have them -- in fact, they are deprecated for portability. See http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.shell/2008-04/msg00790.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm used to them for historical reasons. I will get rid of them. ;-)

Comment: huh, thanks for the heads up... crazy considering my phone has backticks on the hardware keyboard....

Comment: Why feed grep into awk?

DAY=$(awk "/$DATE/"\ '{ print $2 }' feb2010)

Answer (score 0):

month = " 06-02-2010 Workingday " && grep search-string $month

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#!/bin/sh
variable=`grep "06-02-2010" feb2010`
OR
variable=grep "$(date +%d-+%m-%Y)" feb2010
echo $variable should return the good output
```

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't post an OS so here's how you would do this under windows powershell:

```
((select-string -path .\grepme.txt -pattern (get-date -uformat "%m-%d-%Y")).line).split(' ')[2]
```

Select-string is grep's equivalent